# Mysql & PHP Error: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: php, mysql

I'm getting this error when trying to insert data from a form into a database. I know what it means, I just can't figure out why I'm getting it. Perhaps I've been starting at it for too long and have missed something?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
            $q1 = mysql_escape_string($_POST['q1']);
            $q2 = mysql_escape_string($_POST['q2']);
            $q3 = mysql_escape_string($_POST['q3']);            
            $q4 = mysql_escape_string($_POST['q4']);
            $q5 = mysql_escape_string($_POST['q5']);            
            $q6 = mysql_escape_string($_POST['q6']);
            $q7 = mysql_escape_string($_POST['q7']);
            $q8 = mysql_escape_string($_POST['q8']);
            $q9 = mysql_escape_string($_POST['q9']);
            $q10 = mysql_escape_string($_POST['q10']);
            $q11a = mysql_escape_string($_POST['q11a']);
            $q11b = mysql_escape_string($_POST['q11b']);
            $q11c = mysql_escape_string($_POST['q11c']);
            $q11d = mysql_escape_string($_POST['q11d']);
            $q11e = mysql_escape_string($_POST['q11e']);
            $q11f = mysql_escape_string($_POST['q11f']);
            $q11g = mysql_escape_string($_POST['q11g']);
            $q11h = mysql_escape_string($_POST['q11h']);            
            $q12 = mysql_escape_string($_POST['q12']);
            $q13 = mysql_escape_string($_POST['q13']);
            $q14a = mysql_escape_string($_POST['q14a']);
            $q14b = mysql_escape_string($_POST['q14b']);
            $name = mysql_escape_string($_POST['name']);            
            $email = mysql_escape_string($_POST['email']);


            require_once('connection.php');

            $sql="INSERT INTO survey (Question1, Question2, Question3, Question4, Question5, Question6, Question7, Question8, Question9, Question10, Question11A, Question11B, Question11C, Question11D, Question11E, Question11F, Question11G, Question11H, Question12, Question13, Question14A, Question14B, name, email) VALUES ('$q1', '$q2', '$q3', '$q4', '$q5', '$q6', '$q7', '$q8', '$q9', '$q10', '$q11a','$q11b', '$q11c','$q11d', '$q11e', '$q11f','$q11g','$q11h','$q12', '$q13', '$q14a', '$q14b' '$name', '$email')";

            if (!mysql_query($sql,$conn))
              {
              die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
              }

              mysql_close($conn);

    ?>
```

Comment: Perhaps you have a primary Key at Row1, with autoincrement?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a comma missing between:

```
'$q14b' '$name'
```

---

Why do we get this error:

Consider a simple table `temp` with 2 columns `v1` and `v2` of type `varchar`:

```
mysql> desc temp;
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| v1    | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| v2    | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now lets do 2 inserts:

```
mysql> insert into temp(v1,v2) values('foo' 'bar');  // missing comma..gives err.
ERROR 1136 (21S01): Column count doesnt match value count at row 1

mysql> insert into temp(v1,v2) values('foo' 'bar','faz'); // missing comma..no er
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from temp; // 'foobar' got inserted in v1 !!
+--------+------+
| v1     | v2   |
+--------+------+
| foobar | faz  |
+--------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

From these its very clear that **MySQL concatenates two adjacent strings which are separated by space** and when this happens the number of arguments you provide after `values` reduces by `1` and thus its count does not match the number of columns resulting in this error.

Answer (score 2):

Missing comma

```
'$q14b' '$name'
```

should be

```
'$q14b', '$name'
```