# Why does this MySQL query give "error 1136" when inserting values into table

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-error-1136

Query:

```
INSERT INTO Customer2
VALUES (1, 'Mrs','Jill','Hill','2 Step St','Hillington','Uxbridge',
        'Middx''UB10 8XY','020    8999 684') ;
```

Comment: `Column count doesn't match value count`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the little details you gave, this is how that query should look like:

```
INSERT INTO Customer2 VALUES (1, 'Mrs','Jill','Hill','2 Step St','Hillington','Uxbridge','Middx','UB10 8XY','020 8999 684') ;
```

You're missing a comma between Middx and UB10

Answer (score 6):

You are missing a comma between

```
'Middx''UB10 8XY'
       ^
```

When MySql finds two strings separated by nothing or whitespace it **concatenates** them. 
This decreases the number of values in your `values` list by `1` resulting in `1136` error.

You can see a [**demo here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837659/mysql-php-error-column-count-doesnt-match-value-count-at-row-1/3837693#3837693).